# Adding div(s) that contain a drop list and dynamic content, along with more JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

*I am making my way through building a system that uses a bit more JavaScript than I am used to, so please excuse my naivety with the whole mess!*

I have a form with a drop down list, and four input boxes: 
[image]

When a user selects Item A from the drop list, two fields are populated with dynamic data from my database. If they select Item B, the two fields are repopulated with data. This is working just as I'd like.
[image]

I have a button/link below that div that allows the user to "add" another div below it on-the-fly (no page refresh), containing another drop list and four input boxes. This is working okay, too. The user can select an item from the drop list and the input boxes change accordingly.
[image]

**The problem** comes when the user tries to add a third (or any number over the initial add) div to the lot. The drop list will alter the content of the firstly added div but never affects the subsequent divs. I am guessing this has something to do with ids and can *imagine* what is happening in English but cannot put it into anything that works programmatically (due to my limited JS knowledge).
[image]

I tried looping through the second instance of the code to increment #item_select, #item_details and #item_price, but doing this is obviously not the way to make it work as it hasn't helped! lol

Here is the code that I've written so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field white col s3">
        <select class="browser-default" id="item_select1" name="item_select1">
            <option disabled selected value="">
                Choose an item
            </option>

            <option data-description1=
            "This is the detail for the One Page - Basic item."data-price1="500" value="1">
                Basic - One-page Site
            </option>

            <option data-description1=
            "This is the detail for the Additional Basic Pages item."data-price1="100" value="2">
                Basic - Additional Page(s)
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field white col s4">
        <input class="validate" id="item_details1" name="item_details1" type="text">
    </div>

    <div class="input-field white col s2">
        <input class="validate" id="item_price1" name="item_price1" onkeyup="sum1();" type="text" value="_"> <label for="item_price1">Price</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field white col s1">
        <input class="validate" id="item_qty1" onkeyup="sum1();" type="text"> <label for="item_qty1">Qty</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field white col s2">
        <input class="validate" id="item_total1" type="text" value="_">
        <label for="item_total1">Total</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content"></div><i class="tiny material-icons" onclick="addRow()" style="margin-bottom:50px;">add_circle_outline</i><a onclick="addRow()">add another item</a>

<script>
function addRow() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'row';

    div.innerHTML = '<div class="row"><div class="input-field col s3"><select class="browser-default" name="item_select2" id="item_select2"><option value="" disabled selected>Choose an item<\/option><option data-price2="500" data-description2="This is the detail for the One Page - Basic item." value="1">Basic - One-page Site<\/option><option data-price2="100" data-description2="This is the detail for the Additional Basic Pages item." value="2">Basic - Additional Page(s)<\/option><\/select><\/div><div class="input-field white col s4"><input id="item_details2" name="item_details2" type="text" class="validate"><\/div><div class="input-field white col s2"><input id="item_price2" name="item_price2" type="text" class="validate" value="_" onkeyup="sum2();"><\/div><div class="input-field white col s1"><input id="item_qty2" type="text" class="validate" onkeyup="sum2();"><\/div><div class="input-field white col s2"><input id="item_total2" type="text" class="validate" value="_"><\/div><\/div>\
    <i class="tiny material-icons" onclick="removeRow(this)">remove_circle<\/i><a onclick="removeRow(this)" style="color:red;"> remove above row<\/a>';
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}

function removeRow(input) {
    document.getElementById('content').removeChild(input.parentNode);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#item_select1 option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $("#item_details1").attr('data-description1');
        return $(this).val() == $("#item_price1").attr('data-price1');
    }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#item_select1").live("change", function() {
        $("#item_details1").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-description1"));
        $("#item_price1").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-price1"));
    });
});

function sum1() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('item_price1').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('item_qty1').value;
    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('item_total1').value = result;
    }
}

$("#item_select1").change(function() {
    $('#item_qty1').val('');
    $('#item_total1').val('');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#item_select2 option").filter(function() {
        return $(this).val() == $("#item_details2").attr('data-description2');
        return $(this).val() == $("#item_price2").attr('data-price2');
    }).attr('selected', true);

    $("#item_select2").live("change", function() {
        $("#item_details2").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-description2"));
        $("#item_price2").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-price2"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Again, my JavaScript skills are not the greatest, so a very straightforward answer (especially if code samples are involved) would be even more appreciated! :)

Comment: you have tagged `jquery`!! Is it ok if `jquery` solution is provided?? If you see your `addrow` function you are trying to to add duplicate elements into the DOM which  is totally not going to work as you expect!! There are several changes you have to make!!

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle link with all the html,css and JSelements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions for you:

1) You have created the first row in HTML, and the others via JavaScript. Do it all in one place, this will make maintain your code easier later on. In this case, I have done it all in JavaScript.

2) Use class selectors (`.item_qty`) instead of IDs (`#item_qty1`), and then use [jQuery Traversing](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) functions to find the tags that you need. Here I used [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) a lot.

3) I prefer to separate the JS event handlers from HTML code, making use of [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead of `onclick` and such.

4) The [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler has been deprecated and removed since jQuery v1.9. You can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in its place.

Here's the modified code using these suggestions ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/noq0L1eh/)):

```
<div id="content"></div>

<i class="tiny material-icons addRowLink" style="margin-bottom:50px;">add_circle_outline</i><a class="addRowLink">add another item</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    addRow();

    $('#content').on("change", 'select.productSelect', function() {
        $(this).closest('.row').find(".item_details").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-description"));
        $(this).closest('.row').find(".item_price").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-price"));
        $(this).closest('.row').find(".item_price").trigger("change");
    });

    $('#content').on('change keyup', "input.item_qty, input.item_price", function() {
        sum(this);
    });

    $(".addRowLink").on('click', function() {
        addRow();
    });

    $('#content').on('click', '.removeRowLink', function() {
        removeRow(this);
    });

});

function addRow() {
    rowNumber = $('#content .row').length + 1;

    var arr = [
        {value: '', disabled: true, selected: true, text: 'Choose an item'},
        {value: '1', "data-description": "This is the detail for the One Page - Basic item.", "data-price": 500, text: 'Basic - One-page Site'},
        {value: '2', "data-description": "This is the detail for the Additional Basic Pages item.", "data-price": 100, text: 'Basic - Additional Page(s)'},
    ];

    select = $('<select class="browser-default productSelect" name="item_select' + rowNumber + '" id="item_select' + rowNumber + '"></select>');
    $(arr).each(function() {
        select.append($("<option>", this).text(this.text));
    });

    var newRow = $('<div class="row">').append(select);

    var newhtml = '';
    newhtml += '    <div class="input-field white col s4"> \r\n';
    newhtml += '        <input class="validate item_details" name="item_details' + rowNumber + '" type="text" /> \r\n';
    newhtml += '    </div> \r\n';
    newhtml += '    <div class="input-field white col s2"> \r\n';
    newhtml += '        <input class="validate item_price" name="item_price' + rowNumber + '" type="text" value="_" /> <label for="item_price' + rowNumber + '">Price</label> \r\n';
    newhtml += '    </div> \r\n';
    newhtml += '    <div class="input-field white col s1"> \r\n';
    newhtml += '        <input class="validate item_qty" name="item_qty' + rowNumber + '" type="text" /> <label for="item_qty' + rowNumber + '">Qty</label> \r\n';
    newhtml += '    </div> \r\n';
    newhtml += '    <div class="input-field white col s2"> \r\n';
    newhtml += '        <input class="validate item_total" name="item_total' + rowNumber + '" type="text" value="_" /> \r\n';
    newhtml += '        <label for="item_total' + rowNumber + '">Total</label> \r\n';
    newhtml += '    </div> \r\n';

    newRow.append(newhtml);

    if (rowNumber > 1) {
        newRow.append('<i class="tiny material-icons removeRowLink">remove_circle</i><a class="removeRowLink" style="color:red;"> remove above row</a>');
    }

    $('#content').append(newRow);
}

function removeRow(t) {
    $(t).closest('.row').remove();
}

function sum(t) {
    row = $(t).closest('.row');
    var price = row.find('.item_price').val();
    var qty = row.find('.item_qty').val();
    var result = parseInt(price) * parseInt(qty);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        row.find('.item_total').val(result);
    } else {
        row.find('.item_total').val("_");
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: What a fantastic answer. I appreciate that you created a working model that reflects the same elements that I provided. Thank you so much, @marcos-dimitrio

Comment: On quick question (I think):
I need to add this <div class="input-field white col s3"> to the code just before the select statement. However, when I add it within 

    select = $('<select class="browser-default productSelect" name="item_select' + rowNumber + '" id="item_select' + rowNumber + '"></select>');

the drop list blanks out and ceases to function. (See below:)

select = $('<div class="input-field white col s3"><select class="browser-default productSelect" name="item_select' + rowNumber + '" id="item_select' + rowNumber + '"></select>');

Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to close the `div`, since you're wrapping the `select` with it.

Comment: I tried that, but it still yields nothing. Let me post a picture to show you what I mean... http://imgur.com/EXUmtd1  Line 199

Comment: Ha! I figured it out. It was a simple replacement of some CSS. Thank you again! +1000000!

Comment: Oh, you can't do that within that logic. The select must be the first item, because later it's used to add the options! If you want to wrap it within a div, you could do: 
`selectContainer = $('<div class="input-field white col s3">').append(select);`
then
`var newRow = $('<div class="row">').append(selectContainer);`. There are many ways to add HTML to a document using jQuery, try to find some on the internet, it will help a lot. One at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp), another on [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/) site.

Comment: You rock! I really need to brush up on my jQuery skills. Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, its a short proof of concept in a nutshell. Should bring you on the right track.

[jsfiddle goes here](https://jsfiddle.net/2rt6zms1/)

```
(function(){
'use-strict';

//This stores data for the select input. 
//You may extend the select input with additional option field(s) to match this.
var data = [];
data.push({id : 0, text : 'one', price : 500});
data.push({id : 1, text : 'additional', price : 100});

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
button.addEventListener('click', add, false);

var select = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
select[0].addEventListener('change', change, false);

//1. is first input type text and 2. is second one
function change() {
    var divChildElements = this.parentNode.children;
    divChildElements[1].value = '';
    divChildElements[2].value = '';

    divChildElements[1].value = data[this.value].text;
    divChildElements[2].value = data[this.value].price;
}

//This builds your select and input fields
function add() {
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var lastDiv = divs.length-1;
    var inputs = 2;

    select.addEventListener('change', change, false);

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = data[i].id;
        option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].text));
        select.appendChild(option);
    }

    div.appendChild(select);

    for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        div.appendChild(input);
    }


    docFrag.appendChild(div);
    divs[lastDiv].parentNode.insertBefore(docFrag, divs[lastDiv].nextSibling);

}
}());
```

Comment: This is a great answer and the example looks to be quite promising. Thank you for your help/insight!